# MongoDB: Getting SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, ssl-certificate, mongodb

I followed [this](https://datacenteroverlords.com/2012/03/01/creating-your-own-ssl-certificate-authority/) tutorial to create a both a root CA certificate and then used it to sign a key for the mongod server.
I run monogd with this configuration, by following this [doc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl/):

```
  net:
    ssl:
      mode: requireSSL
      PEMKeyFile: /home/user/device.pem
      CAFile: /home/user/rootCA.pem
      allowInvalidCertificates: true
      allowInvalidHostnames: true
```

The 2 last ones I added since I am getting a connection failure.

I'm using these lines to connect:

```
./mongo <host>:<port>/<db>  -u <user> -p <pwd> --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates --sslCAFile ~/Downloads/rootCA.pem

./mongo <host>:<port>/<db>  -u <user> -p <pwd> --ssl --sslAllowInvalidCertificates

./mongo <host>:<port>/<db>  -u <user> -p <pwd> --ssl
```

But all of these produce:

```
MongoDB shell version v3.4.2
connecting to: mongodb://<host>:<port>/<db>
2017-03-30T14:39:15.307+0300 E NETWORK  [thread1] SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate
2017-03-30T14:39:15.311+0300 E QUERY    [thread1] Error: socket exception [CONNECT_ERROR] for SSL peer certificate validation failed: self signed certificate :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:237:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Any idea what am I doing wrong? I know it's a self signed certificate
Will appreciate your help

Also tried following the answer in here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21297139/how-do-you-sign-certificate-signing-request-with-your-certification-authority/21340898#21340898

Answer (score 3):

In your [mongod](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongod/) configuration file, you specify [SSL mode](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.ssl.mode) to be `requireSSL`. This means that the `mongod` server, *only* uses and accepts TLS/SSL encrypted connections.

The client `mongo` shell in your case, needs to specify [--sslPEMKeyFile](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongo/#cmdoption-sslpemkeyfile) to pass the clients PEM file. 
See also [mongo shell SSL configuration](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/#mongo-shell-ssl-configuration) or [Tutorial: configure SSL for clients](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/configure-ssl-clients/).

> The 2 last ones I added since I am getting a connection failure.

In regards to security, be extra careful enabling configurations. Please see the two parameters description for what they're for : 
[--allowInvalidCertificates](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.ssl.allowInvalidCertificates) and 
[--allowInvalidHostnames](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#net.ssl.allowInvalidHostnames)

Comment: Are you sure that clients have to have certificates? I understood that's the case only if I specify the CAFile parameter as well. regarding security, of course I'm only trying to relax the restrictions as far as possible to make the connection work and then restrict it again once I figure out what is wrong, and it's not production or have any data in it at all...